# How to fix the target vertical position for Smooth Scrolls in that piece of code? JQuery only

Tags: jquery

I'm using a smooth scroll script found in Codepen:

```
// Select all links with hashes
$('a[href*="#"]')
// Remove links that don't actually link to anything
.not('[href="#"]')
.not('[href="#0"]')
.click(function(event) {
  // On-page links
  if (
    location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') 
    && 
    location.hostname == this.hostname
  ) {
    // Figure out element to scroll to
    var target = $(this.hash);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
    // Does a scroll target exist?
    if (target.length) {
      // Only prevent default if animation is actually gonna happen
      event.preventDefault();
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
      }, 1000, function() {
        // Callback after animation
        // Must change focus!
        var $target = $(target);
        $target.focus();
        if ($target.is(":focus")) { // Checking if the target was focused
          return false;
        } else {
          $target.attr('tabindex','-1'); // Adding tabindex for elements not focusable
          $target.focus(); // Set focus again
        };
      });
    }
  }
});
```

The scrolling works but the targets are being partially located hidden under the horizontal menu (fixed at 0 top)

The horizontal menú has a height=150px;

I wonder if there is a simple way to adjust the position the targets should reach. The only one that works correctly at the moment is "top".

I also wonder why "top" only works if I add "#" when defining the ID (id = "# top"). The other targets do not work if that symbol is added to them. I imagine that "#" is defining the initial position. Wrong? Wright? TY.

Comment: You could try `scrollTop: target.offset().top - $(horizontalMenu).outerHeight()` which should adjust the scroll offset. Can you create a JSFiddle to replicate the issue?

Comment: Thank you user7290573. I'll give a try.

Comment: @user7290573 Worked as a charm. Thank you. Please add it as an answer in order to mark it as the right one. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply subtract the value returned from `.outerHeight()`¹ from `target.offset().top`:

```
scrollTop: target.offset().top - $(horizontalMenu).outerHeight()
```

---

¹ https://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/